# Lisp: remove all a's from a given list and return non-a values

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I tried to return every elements in the list that doesn’t match with "a".
Here is what i tried so far.

```
(defun removeA (arr) 
     (cond((null arr) nil) 
          ((if (listp (car arr))
               (or (removeA (car arr)) (removeA (cdr arr)))
          (if (eql 'a (car arr))      
              (removeA (cdr arr)) 
          (cons (car arr) (removeA (cdr arr)))
)
))
)
```

)
(print (removeA '(a (a) (v a e) (a a) d)))

```
here is the output: (V E)

i need help on why its not printing "D" as well
```

Comment: Hints: the first thing you need to do is to post correctly indented code. The code you posted is not correctly indented. The next thing then: check the syntax of COND and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: What result is expected? Should it be `(v e d)`, or `((v e) d)`, or `(() (v e) () d)`,...? `cond` is already a conditional form: why the nested `if` forms? Proper code formatting will help everyone, yourself included, read your lisp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for the program appears to be this:

- Input is a list, of individual items or lists
- If individual item, remove it if it is the value 'a'
- If a list, remove all items within it with value 'a'

My first reaction is to map a function over the input list, using `mapcar` or something similar - if you are using `car` or `cdr` it's worth checking to see if there is a higher level way of doing the same thing.

However, I am advised that using `mapcar` is inefficient, and a better approach is to use `loop`. The `loop` construct is a macro, with `loop` in the function position, followed by an English-style series of words.

```
(defun remove-a (lst)
  (loop
   for x in lst
   if (listp x) collect (remove-if #'isa-p x)
   else collect (if (isa-p x) nil x)))

(defun isa-p (val) (equal val 'a))
```

Hence:

```
(remove-a  '(a (a) (v a e) (a a) d))
(NIL NIL (V E) NIL D)
```

The result can be flattened into a single list using `Alexandria:flatten`, which you need to load first with `(ql:quicklisp 'Alexandria)`.

If you want to use `car` and `cdr`, my comments are as follows.

What you are supplying as an input is a list, but you call it `arr`, suggesting an array; arrays are very different things in Common Lisp.

You've got your `if` and `cond` the wrong way around. The function `cond` is like `switch-case` in other languages. You want to check for an empty list with `if`, before considering the various possibilities with `cond`.

You are using `print` to show the results. This is not necessary if you are using a REPL. `(print a)` and `a` are equivalent in a REPL.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution:

```lisp
(defun removeA (ls)
  (let ((withoutA
          (if (consp ls)
            (remove-if #'(lambda (l) (equal l 'a)) ls)
            ls)))
    (if (consp ls)
      (mapcar #'removeA withoutA)
      ls)))

(print
  (removeA '(a (a) (v a e) (a a) d)))
```

That prints `(NIL (V E) NIL D)`.

The `NIL`s representing the empty lists.